# How can I access the Component Template ID from within my Component DWT?

Tags: tridion

In the HTML template for my Component I need to write out the TCM URI of the Component Template:

```
<!-- Start Component Presentation: {"ComponentID" : "@@Component.ID@@",
                        "ComponentTemplateID" : "@@ComponentTemplate.ID@@" } -->
```

But unfortunately `ComponentTemplate.ID` doesn't exist.

How can I access the Component Template ID from within my Component DWT?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm afraid you'll have to write a C# TBB (fragment or assembly):

```cs
TcmUri templateId = engine.PublishingContext.ResolvedItem.Template.Id;
if (templateId.ItemType == ItemType.ComponentTemplate) {
    Item item = package.CreateStringItem(ContentType.Text, templateId.ToString());
    package.PushItem("ComponentTemplateID", item);
}
```

You can only access the ComponentTemplate.ID from within a Page DWT layout...

Comment: Not exactly 'access' but if the DWT is used only with a certain template, could you hard-code it? What am I saying, this is @Frank we're talking about.

Comment: This may be Frank, but he's in this case working on a somewhat realistic web site for once. So unfortunately hard-coding it is not an option. Writing tons of code to solve the problem, is an option though; so I am so far taking Mihai's suggestion, but then put it in a function source that I can call from my DWT @@GetComponentTemplate()@@

Comment: Maybe tons of code isn't needed. Apparently @@ID@@ returns the Component Template ID in Preview and Publishing, but not Template Builder. For example, `@@Component.ID@@ @@ID@@` gives me `tcm:6-1541 tcm:6-1541` in Template Builder, but  `tcm:6-1541 tcm:7-81-32` in Preview.

Answer (score 1):

Add a "ComponentTemplateID" parameter to the Template Invocation in the compound template. You can then access this in the same way as package variables.

Comment: Although an interesting alternative, I would still have to type that parameter value in manually. Thus action like copy/pasting, porting or localizing the CT will render the parameter value incorrect.

Comment: Indeed Frank. I often prefer to do things with configuration rather than code, but maybe I've gone a bit far. I don't mind someone who copy/pastes having to fix it up, and I don't mind having a technical design that outlaws localizing the CT, but the porting problem is just too nasty. +1 to Mihai's solution then.

Answer (score 1):

`@@ID@@` will give you the Component Template TCM URI when previewing (in the CME, not in the Template Builder) or Publishing.